# Odata url not returning count

Tags: count, odata

I am trying to check total records with a filter on a odata query. But it throws error

```
<m:message>Could not find a property named '$count' on type 'Edm.Boolean'.</m:message>
```

Any suggestions?

```
https://testodataurl.com/testService.svc/Entity?$filter=(Id eq 377 and MSF eq 'Good')/$count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$count is not a query option. It should appear before query options.

So try

> https://testodataurl.com/testService.svc/Entity/$count/?$filter=(Id eq
>   377 and MSF eq 'Good')